# Posting to XML with cURL, Noob here learning

Tags: php, curl

Hi I'm trying to program with cURL.
But haven't started also it return me wit server internal error.
Is there any wrong with the given code in the cURL?

```
<?php';
$now = new DateTime();
$url = "smsx.ia.com.my";
$parameters = array(
'UserID' => 'something@gmail..com',
'Version' => '1.0',
'Action' => 'ProductCreate',
'Timestamp' => $now->format(DateTime::ISO8601),
);
// Sort parameters by name
ksort($parameters);
$params = array();
foreach ($parameters as $name => $value) {
$params[] = rawurlencode($name) . '=' . rawurlencode($value);
}
$strToSign = implode('&', $params);
// Compute signature and add it to the parameters
$parameters['Signature'] =
rawurlencode(hash_hmac('sha256', $strToSign, $api_key, false));

// Build Query String
$queryString = http_build_query($parameters, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
// Open Curl connection
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url."?".$queryString);
// Save response to the variable $data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlPayload);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
// Close Curl connection
curl_close($ch);

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {


}

?>

<form action="" method="post">

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

So I'm trying to post information to the URL, but i just load the site and it gives me system internal error.
Can't proceed with it.

Any idea why I'm facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are posting XML data then you have to specify the server that you are sending XML in post data. I can't see this in your code.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8'));
```

Secondly, make sure your are preparing your `$queryString` thing correctly. Otherwise it may raise internal server error too.

Finally, just curious, are you sure about `';` after `<?php` at the first line of your code?